# How to use the output of an array formula in subsequent calculations?

Tags: regex, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet where I'm getting the duration of a Youtube video as follows:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),"PT(\d+)M(\d+)S")
```

This gives me two cells with two values (minutes and seconds). However, I want to perform further calculations on them (multiply the minutes by 60 and add the seconds). How can I 'access' these values within a function, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the duration time as the unit of the second.
- You want to achieve this using the built-in formulas of Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about these sample formulas?

#### Sample formula:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),"PT(\d+)M(\d+)S","00:$1:$2")*24*3600)
```

- In this sample formula, the cell "A2" has the URL like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=###`.
- The retrieved duration time is converted to the time format, and the value is retrieved as the second.

  - For example, when `IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content")` returns `PT1M10S`, `VALUE(REGEXREPLACE("PT1M10S","PT(\d+)M(\d+)S","00:$1:$2")*24*3600)` returns `70`.
  - Even when the time is more than 1 hour, for example, the value like `PT123M45S` is returned. And `=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE("PT123M45S","PT(\d+)M(\d+)S","00:$1:$2")*24*3600)` returns `7425`.

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

As other pattern, if you want to use `=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),"PT(\d+)M(\d+)S")`, how about the following formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),"PT(\d+)M(\d+)S"))),"SELECT Col1*60+Col2 label Col1*60+Col2 ''")
```

- In this formula, values from the array are used and calculated.

Answer (score 0):

or like this:

```
=TEXT(VALUE("00:"&SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"), "PT|S", ), "M",":")), "[ss]")*1
```

or shortest:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"), 
 "PT(\d+)M(\d+)S", "00:$1:$2")*86400
```